# Get rid of windows tab highlighting for WPF Tab Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF tab control. However, when a tab is selected, the TabItem Header changes background color. I think that this is caused by the local Windows settings for highlighting/selection items. How do I disable this? I want the TabItem Header to remain the same regardless of wether it is selected or not.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can override the default template for `TabItem` either in Blend or through XAML.

Comment: thats going to be more trouble than its worth. once you override the default template you will have to build it from the ground up.

Comment: @RadioSpace there must be a better way than this. In Winforms this would be a single property. I really don't like WPF some times

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the [system colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) for a control using syntax like this:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

(I'm not sure if I have the right [SystemColors Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) for you or not - may need to test to find the right one causing your problem)

Comment: That's a ton of options to test through. Surely there must be a better way. There is no OOTB way to do this???

Comment: @JimBeam You wouldn't need to test every single one individually... most are totally unrelated to the Control Highlight color. If `HighlightBrushKey` doesn't work, just pick a few others from the list which look likely, overwrite all of them with different colors, and see which color shows up when you run it.